# Not able to create the object for HttpRequest in order to write unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, httprequest, xunit

I am writing the unit tests for the method which accepts the HttpRequest parameter of the class Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http . As it is the abstract class , I cannot instantiate it .

My Input method is :

```
  public static RequestParameters GetInputParameters(HttpRequest req)
    {
        RequestParameters requestParameters = new RequestParameters();
        if (req.GetQueryParameterDictionary().ContainsKey("Models"))
        {
            string models = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["Models"]) ?
                Constants.Constants.ModelsDefaultValue :
                req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["Models"];

            List<string> modelList = new List<string>();
            
            var getModelList = models?.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            if (getModelList == null)
            {
                modelList.Add(Constants.Constants.ModelsDefaultValue);
            }
            else if (getModelList.Length == 1)
            {
                modelList.Add(getModelList[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in getModelList)
                {
                    Match match = Regex.Match(item, @"'([^']*)");
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        modelList.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            requestParameters.modelList = modelList;
        }
        else
        {
            requestParameters.modelList.Add(Constants.Constants.ModelsDefaultValue);
        }

        if (req.GetQueryParameterDictionary().ContainsKey("timestamp"))
        {
            requestParameters.timestamp = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["timestamp"]) ?
                Constants.Constants.TimestampDefaultValue :
                req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["timestamp"];
        }
        else
        {
            requestParameters.timestamp = Constants.Constants.TimestampDefaultValue;
        }

        if (req.GetQueryParameterDictionary().ContainsKey("timespan"))
        {
            requestParameters.timespan = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["timespan"]) ?
                Constants.Constants.TimeSpanDefaultValue :
                req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["timespan"];
        }
        else
        {
            requestParameters.timespan = Constants.Constants.TimeSpanDefaultValue;
        }


        if (req.GetQueryParameterDictionary().ContainsKey("variable"))
        {
            requestParameters.variable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["variable"]) ? "severity" : req.GetQueryParameterDictionary()["variable"];
        }
        else
        {
            requestParameters.variable = "severity";
        }
        return requestParameters;
    }
```

Azure Function has following input parameters :

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "variables/assetTrend")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
```

I want to write unit test for this in order to test all these conditions .I can try mocking the httprequest and pass mocked object to the caller function of this but I cannot do it as the main function returns either OkayObjectResult or BadObjectResult and in that case I cannot check the values getting passed for the variables .Is there any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Please show your code as text, not as an image. If it's an object class, it's logical to conclude that it has a derived type that's being used. You can either find that type and use it, or create your own derived type.

Comment: I have replaced the image with the code . Please review .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mock HttpRequest and use it. something like this

```
private MockQueryParameters(string param1, string param2)
{
    var paramsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>
    {
        { "param1", param1 },
        { "param2", param2 }
    };
 
    _mockRequest.Setup(i => i.Query).Returns(new QueryCollection(paramsDictionary));
}
```

Please find the details example using the link
[Unit Testing](https://mahmutcanga.com/2019/12/13/unit-testing-httprequest-in-c/)